# Parsing Dynamic Data

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

I am trying to parse JSON using a dynamics object. Here is the library, the JSON Data Translator, that I am using: https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/shopify.net

Here is my error message:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'string' does
>   not contain a definition for 'products'

Here is my JSON:

http://pastebin.com/pnmz7jN0

Here is my code:

```
    public void GetProducts()
    {
        // The JSON Data Translator will automatically decode the JSON for you
        dynamic data = _api.Get("/admin/products.json");

        // the dynamic object will have all the fields just like in the API Docs
        foreach (var product in data.products)
        {
            Console.Write(product.title);
        }
    }
```

I have tried data.products and data, but I cannot get the product object inside.

Comment: Show us the implementation of this "JSON Data Translator".

Comment: Does the json object have a title property?

Comment: I added the code and yes, there is a title property.

Comment: Did you use this constructor? `var api = new ShopifyAPIClient(authState, new JsonDataTranslator());`

Answer (score 0):

Consider `data[0].title` for start, but in debug mode you should be able to navigate through object, or use immediate window and run some manual queries.

Regarding the error it seems like your `dynamic data` may be just a string object, try your own code just remove word "products".

```
public void GetProducts()
{
    // The JSON Data Translator will automatically decode the JSON for you
    dynamic data = _api.Get("/admin/products.json");

    // the dynamic object will have all the fields just like in the API Docs
    foreach (var product in data) //here is the change from the code you posted
    {
        Console.Write(product.title);
    }
}
```

[image: Your sample data parsed]

Comment: How can the change from `data.products` to `data` be the solution in this scenario?!

Comment: because dynamic data may be an array already, if you do data.products this means you refer to dynamic object called data and to it's property "products". The fact that JSON notation has name does not mean that whatever API you use will deserialize it using names. Look at the picture again, dynamic object data may be an array thus instead of foreach(p in data.products) try foreach(p in data)

Comment: BTW, my example is "dry try". I didn't test the approach in runtime. Can't test it I'm not sure what "_api" refers to even if JSON Data Translator is mentioned, or in other words I'm too lazy :)